# Can I query documents with undefined properties more efficiently in DocumentDB than with IS_DEFINED

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a documentdb which I need to query a date property.  I could initialize the date property to null when i create the document,  but i might have a few paths like this:

```
Document.PathA.Date
Document.PathB.Date
Document.PathC.Date
```

Not all documents may need PathA or PathC so i dont want to just insert nulls all over the place.  I also may need to insert a new PathD after a document's initial creation.

When I use IS_DEFINED on one of these paths It uses a very long running scan,  which is understandable but something i'd like to avoid.  Is there a way i can change my index for the collection so that i can query missing paths faster?

Comment: You could try using the null coalescor, ie. "SELECT f.lastName ?? f.surname AS familyName
FROM Families f."  - but I strongly suspect it will do a scan as well, although possibly an index scan. Worth a try though. Some info on how to do the equivalent in the .NET SDK here: http://blog.lytzen.name/2016/09/find-documents-with-missing-properties.html.  not posting as answer as I suspect it won't help :)